# Which diameter of pipe to be used from overhead reservoir to Outlet (1.5 bar pressure with 15 mm diameter pipe)..?

Tags: plumbing

One outlet point having 15 mm diameter is required having pressure 1.5 Bar.
Dimension of overhead reservoir is 0.5 diameter and 0.3 height.
The head difference approximately 6 meters.
Which diameter of pipe to be used from overhead reservoir to Outlet...??? Advance thanks to all of you for your reply.

Comment: WE need a lot more information than a few dimensions  and some pressures. How about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems like you are thinking that the size of the components and pipe are related to the pressure at the bottom; they are not. Height (head) of the water column determines the outlet pressure, regardless of pipe size.

Comment: Of course, outlet pressure will depend on pipe size and length if there is flow, but you haven't specified what the flow might be.